# looping json object using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

My json object looks like below and i want to loop only 'data'. when i am trying to access with `objparse.data` , it is throwing null. Please suggest me how to loop the 'data' in objparse object.

```
objparse =  "{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"data\":[{\"vehModelCode\":\"0824\",\"vehModelDesc\":\"xA\"},{\"vehModelCode\":\"0825\",\"vehModelDesc\":\"xB\"},]}"
```

Comment: That's a JSON string, not an object...

Comment: As objParse is String, so it is throwing null. Try to use : var newObj = eval(objparse); And then use newObj.data.

Comment: Also consider using [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) - then have the callback (second argument) accept an argument like `responseData` and utilize `responseData.data`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check example:

```
var objparsed =  {"success":true,"message":"","data":[{"vehModelCode":"0824","vehModelDesc":"xA"},{"vehModelCode":"0825","vehModelDesc":"xB"}]};
for (var z in objparsed['data']) {
    console.log(objparsed['data'][z]);
}
var objparse =  '{"success":true,"message":"","data":[{"vehModelCode":"0824","vehModelDesc":"xA"},{"vehModelCode":"0825","vehModelDesc":"xB"}]}';
var result = JSON.parse(objparse);
for (var z in result['data']) {
    console.log(result['data'][z]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue with your example is that the JSON is invalid due to the trailing comma, so passing it to `JSON.parse()` fails.

`..."vehModelDesc\":\"xB\"},]}"` should be `"vehModelDesc\":\"xB\"}]}"` (removed the final comma).

Once that's fixed you can do:

`var mydata = JSON.parse(object).data`

and then `mydata` will be an Array type that you can call any of the array methods on (`map`, `forEach`, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You should parse the JSON string first.

```
var data = JSON.parse(objparse).data;
data.forEach(function(model){
  /* DO STUFF */
});
```

Comment: var data = JSON.parse(objparse).data; throwing as [object][object]

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can do as the following code snippet

```js
var objparse =  "{\"success\":true,\"message\":\"\",\"data\":[{\"vehModelCode\":\"0824\",\"vehModelDesc\":\"xA\"},{\"vehModelCode\":\"0825\",\"vehModelDesc\":\"xB\"},]}"
var obj = eval("(" +objparse + ')');
obj.data.forEach(function(model){alert(model);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps